# Unable to locate file when code moved to CloudHub

Tags: java, mule, cloudhub

**Usecase**: Reading File contents in Java **(Deployed at cloud-hub)**.

**Problem**: 
I have written a java class which reads file and contents are log to console.But if same code is moved to cloud Hub, File-not-Found exception is raised.

**Question**: I understand that src/main/resources folder structure will not be available,what should be the location of file to be used while creating the *File* instance if code is running through cloudhub

Here is the code snippet works only in Local environment.

```
package com.testUtil;

import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;

public class TestClass implements Callable {

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Files and directories present at src/main/resources are :");

            File folder = new File("./src/main/resources/");
            File[] listOfFiles5 = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles5.length; i++) {
              if (listOfFiles5[i].isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles5[i].getName());
              } else if (listOfFiles5[i].isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles5[i].getName());
              }
            }

        System.out.println("expected output is: xsd");


        FileReader fr = new FileReader(folder+"/xsd/Request.xsd"); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        String contents=""; 
        String s=""; 
        while((s = br.readLine()) != null) { 

            contents+=s;
        } 
        System.out.println(contents);
        fr.close(); 


        return contents;
    }

}
```

But

```
   this.getClass().getResource("./").getPath();
```

gives  ***./mule-3.4.1-R35/conf*** as output.

So was trying with below snnipet,but still FileNotFoundException

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(this.getClass().getResource("./").getPath()+"/xsd/Request.xsd");
```

Please Help !!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Files in `src/main/resources` should be loaded with the classpath, not as files.

I recommend using [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) for scanning the classpath efficiently.